# Tie an Optionmenu to an array in Perl TK

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

i need to automatically update an optionmenu in Perl Tk by tying an array to an Optionmenu if possible.

To give an example, i can do this successfully with a listbox:

```
tie @datafile, "Tk::Listbox", $lb;
```

However, when I try doing the same for an Optionmenu it fails to AUTOLOAD.

```
tie @optionfile, "Tk::Optionmenu", $om;
```

Is this not possible? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: A tie interface is not implemented for `Tk::Optionmenu`. But I accept patches :-)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the module I noticed a solution, although longer--still a solution. I hope this helps someone out there working with this old stuff.

Here is the module: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SREZIC/Tk-804.031/Tk/Optionmenu.pm

Adding an option to the optionmenu

```
# Add to the array 
push @datafile3, $newReport;
# Add to the optionmenu
$om->addOptions($newReport);
```

Then the removal

```
# removing an option from the array and also the optionmenu itself. 
my $index = 0;

# remove from array
$index++ until $datafile3[$index] eq $selectBatch;
splice(@datafile3, $index, 1);
# remove from menu
$om->configure( -options  => [@datafile3]);
```